# Issues with makefiles when installing ARPACK

Tags: linux, makefile, installation, arpack

I'm currently trying to install ARPACK so that I can use sparse matrices in Armadillo for large information networks. The instructions for

However, when I try running `make lib` after altering the directory the files are in, but I run into trouble with this line of the README

```
7. Do "make lib" in the current directory to build the standard library 
   "libarpack_$(PLAT).a"
```

In the subfolders, there are only four different files for platforms, which are

```
ARmake.CRAY
ARmake.SGI
ARmake.SP2
ARmake.SUN4
```

The default is SUN4, and the file for the platform must exist because of the line

```
ARPACKLIB  = $(home)/libarpack_$(PLAT).a
```

included in the makefile.  However, my computer has Sandy Bridge architecture (Ubuntu 12.04) and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use that file.

Additionally, I get the following error after running the `make lib` command (which is `make all` in this context):

```
me@mycomp:~/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK$ make lib
Making lib in /home/me/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK/BLAS
/bin/sh: 6: /bin/make: not found
Making lib in /home/me/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK/LAPACK
/bin/sh: 6: /bin/make: not found
Making lib in /home/me/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK/UTIL
/bin/sh: 6: /bin/make: not found
Making lib in /home/me/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK/SRC
/bin/sh: 6: /bin/make: not found
ranlib /home/me/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK/libarpack_SUN4.a
ranlib: '/home/me/devel/ARPACK2/ARPACK/libarpack_SUN4.a': No such file
make: *** [arpacklib] Error 1
```

I just installed LAPACK and OpenBLAS using `make`, but for some reason I'm running into issues here.  I'm not very experienced installing libraries, but the documentation I've come across hasn't helped me get past this point.

Comment: is there a reason for installing ARPACK manually? there are pre-built packages for Ubuntu, as well as other Linux distributions. simply look for it in the Ubuntu software center. It might be called arpack-ng.

Answer (score 4):

In `ARmake.inc` you need to change line `home = $(HOME)/ARPACK` if you want to build it to some other location (as written in the README file).  `libarpack_$(PLAT).a` will then be stored there, e.g. `/home/username/arpack/ARPACK`

Also change `PLAT = LINUX`.

and the errors you see are due to the incorrect location of `make`.

In `ARmake.inc`, update `MAKE = /usr/bin/make` to the correct location of `make`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate your "make" command, probably it is at /usr/bin/make.
In ARmake.inc you must to especify correct path to "make" command.